# Using multiple threads (or handlers) but Android UI-Thread still stucks?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout, android-fragments

> I have implemented ticker using textview, by translating
>   textview using setX() method.
>
> On imageview I have to show multiple
>   images, flip one by one.
>
> since both have to be run parallel and continuous.

I have implement this using handler than using thread.

## Using Handler;

**TickerHandler**, updates setX() value continuously after some seconds, thus ticker like effect is produce working ok.

```
new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                currentX = tv.getX();

                if ((currentX + 10) > 600) {
                    tv.setX(10);
                }
                tv.setX(currentX + 5);

                this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 50);
            }
        }.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

**FlipHandler**, updates new image on imageview, flipping images, working ok.

```
new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                imgV.setImageResource(images[imgCount % 5]);

                imgCount++;
                if (imgCount > 5) {
                    imgCount = imgCount % 5;
                }
                this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 500);
            }
        }.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

## Using Thread;

Similarly in threads, since android dont allow other thread to communicate with UI. Therefore, runOnUiThread is must to communicate with UI.

Both ticker and image flipper working ok.

## Problem facing;

Q> When image changes the ticker is stuck for miliseconds, due to which ticker is not  running smooth, ticker give jerking effect.

## Reasons for the problem what I think

- Though I have different Threads, but when I am calling setX() to translate textview, and imageView.setImage????(.....). I have to call them on **UiThread**. Thats why when image is change and setImage() is called setX() wait and TextView stop translate for that time causing jerking effect.

Any idea about this how can I overcome with this situation.

Thanks;

Comment: post the relevant code.

Comment: I have already homework on this and tried different approach as I mentioned above using handler or using thread. Even I have come to conclusion that this is due to UiThread. There is not the problem with my code. I ask for some alternative, besides Handler or Thread or AsyncTask. To overcome the issue.

Comment: if some one need further detail can ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches will eventually use a handler on the UI thread: `runOnUiThread()` will post the runnable to the UI thread handler if the current thread is not the UI thread.

When the handler is processing a message, "obviously" it cannot process other messages.

Things you can change to make things smoother:

- Use the [animations framework](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) for your animations instead of custom handler messages.
- Offload bitmap I/O and decoding to a background thread. In UI thread just switch in the pre-decoded image bitmap to the image view. [Reference](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html).

Comment: thanks buddy, your suggestions worked little bit. atleast someone there to help instead of just negative comments if they cant help.

Comment: your suggestions works. Thanks!